# Не переведены фразы по миграции

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора, перенос-вопросов

> This question was migrated to Stack Overflow на русском because it can be answered by программистов. Migrated прямо сейчас by Qwertiy♦.

[image: скриншот migrated to]

> This question was migrated from Stack Overflow на русском Meta, our discussion, support, and feature requests site. Migrated 1 минуту назад.

[image: скриншот migrated from]

> Clear migration history

> Unlock

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Suvitruf, не всё переведено: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1068096/178988 - по-прежнему на английском: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVsLe.png

Comment: До дома доберусь, посмотрю.

Comment: Появилося после апдейта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Утвердил варианты от MSDN.Knight:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14054

   > Этот вопрос был перенесён на $baseHostAddress$.
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14051

   > Этот вопрос был перенесён на $destinationUrl$, чтобы на него могли дать ответ на подходящем языке.
3. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14053

   > Этот вопрос был перенесён на $toSiteName$, так как на него могут дать ответ на сайте $destinationSiteAudience$.

Добавил для https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14055 перевод:

> Этот вопрос был перенесён на $toSiteName$, наш сайт для обсуждений, поддержки и предложений для этого сайта.

По остальным фразам тоже перевод добавил.

Comment: Еще https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14050 без перевода, добавил вариант.

Comment: @insolor утвердил.